# How to find an unminified angular source to replace opensource.keycdn.com on Plunker?

Tags: angularjs, cdn, plunker

I'm experiencing a weird error on Plunker, but the line having the issue is buried in the unreadable "minified" version of angular.js, specifically:

> ... at https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:6:412

So I want to look at the unminified version of angular.js to see if the error makes more sense.

Here's the call to the minified library supplied by plunker:

```
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" 
  data-semver="1.5.8" 
  src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

And I changed it to:

```
../1.5.8/angular.js
```

But I'm getting a [404](https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js). My guess is that `opensource.keycdn.com` only supplies minified versions of libraries. How do I tell Plunker I want to use a non-minified version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single bit of angular code is in here https://code.angularjs.org/

Edit: Try this

```
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" 
  data-semver="1.5.8" 
  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but it doesn't really answer my question. What url do I use to make plunker use angular 1.5.8? Do you have a plunker I could see?

Comment: Updated the answer changed the src value to get it from a different location.